# Azure Portal's App Registration shows "Network error" when updating an app

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm not able to update my Application Registration in Azure Portal. I consistently get "Network error: There is an issue establishing a connection to the service" : 
[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjDu5.png)

I am able to view my App Registrations, and create new App registrations. Only when I save them, the update fails.

The application registration experience:
https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade

I am the owner of these apps or the tenant administrator.

I noticed that all network requests to graph.windows.net with http verb PATCH fails. POST, GET, etc work. The same requests work when I'm not on my corporate network. What action can I take to determine the root cause and fix this?

Comment: You mentioned the same requests work when you are not on the Corporate network. 1) Does the network have strict Security Policies/ACLs? 2) Are your tests conducted on the same workstation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the case is your web filter does not support the HTTP PATCH verb.  On [some versions of Cisco WSA](https://quickview.cloudapps.cisco.com/quickview/bug/CSCuj39346) the verb is not supported at all.  On version 11+, the verb must be enabled explicitly with the [httppatchconfig](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/wsa/wsa11-5/user_guide/b_WSA_UserGuide_11_5_1/b_WSA_UserGuide_11_5_1_appendix_011000.html) config

You can also set implicit TLS inspection mode for graph.windows.net - this will allow the HTTPS request to pass through the WSA unmodified